# Error importing plugin "sqlmypy": No module named 'sqlmypy'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy, pipenv

I have `sqlalchemy-stubs` installed via my Pipfile:

```
[dev-packages]
sqlalchemy-stubs = {editable = true, git = "https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs.git"}
```

Verified by running `pipenv graph`:

```
sqlalchemy-stubs==0.4
  - mypy [required: >=0.790, installed: 0.910]
    - mypy-extensions [required: >=0.4.3,<0.5.0, installed: 0.4.3]
    - toml [required: Any, installed: 0.10.2]
    - typing-extensions [required: >=3.7.4, installed: 4.0.0]
  - typing-extensions [required: >=3.7.4, installed: 4.0.0]
```

However when running mypy (`mypy --strict .`) with the config:

```
[mypy]
plugins = graphene_plugin, sqlmypy
```

I get the error:

```
error: Error importing plugin "sqlmypy": No module named 'sqlmypy'
```

What is going on?

Comment: After I install `sqlalchemy-stubs`. My error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by removing the `editable = true` from the pipfile.